# How to rotate image automatically in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

Currently, i'm working on an offline signature verification. So, what i want to do now is to find the specific value of rotation for that particular signature image. In this case, i want to normalize the baseline of the signature along with the horizontal axis:
[image].
I've tried to do some coding,

```
v1(1) = column2 - column1;
v1(2) = row2 - row1;
v2(1) = column2 - column1;
v2(2) = row1 - row1;
x1 = v1(1);
y1 = v1(2);
x2 = v2(1);
y2 = v2(2);

dotproduct = (x1*x2 + y1*y2);

v1mag = sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1);
v2mag = sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);

costheta = dotproduct/(v1mag*v2mag);
angle = acos(costheta);

angleDeg = rad2deg(angle);
angleDeg = uint8(angleDeg);
angleDeg

%B = imrotate(invImg,-(angleDeg),'bilinear');
```

As you can see from the coding, variable 'angleDeg' holds the value of rotation angle. Before, I've used imrotate() MATLAB but the problem is that I must input the value of the angle manually instead of calling the variable of 'angleDeg'. Is there any other method/algorithm to rotate an image by calling the variable that holds the angle value beside imrotate()?

Comment: why do you cast the rotation argument to `uint8`?

Comment: Shai has it - there's nothing wrong with the way you're calling imrotate as long as angleDeg is of a format that can take negative values.  Check the output of `-angleDeg` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: thank you to all of you for helping me.. seems that i made a silly mistake here.. the codes work well now..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to input the angle manually?  Why do you cast `angleDeg` to uint8?

By the way, the function `regionprops` can give you the 'Orientation' of the connected component in a binary image, i. e. the angle between the major axis of the component and the horizontal.